# filter mysql inner join one to many results using and

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

i have two tables for example

users

```
----------------------------------
id  | name | blah
----------------------------------
1   | Samy | stackoverflow
2   | jhon | some thing
----------------------------------
```

skills

```
---------------------------------------
id | user_id | skill_title | level
---------------------------------------
1  | 1       | php         | good
2  | 1       | css         | excellent
3  | 1       | photoshop   | fair
4  | 2       | php         | good
---------------------------------------
```

and i run query like this

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN skills ON users.id = skills.user_id
WHERE ($skill_title[0] LIKE 'skills_title' AND 
       $skill_title[1] LIKE 'skills_title')
```

where $skill_title is an array 
what i need is to select user who have all this skills ie PHP,CSS
if i did query like above it will never bring data because it compare every single record to all array element AND if i replaced and with Or it will work but it will no't bring user with all skills

any ideas ?

Comment: How many skills are you going to search for at one time?

Comment: it will be variable may be 10 great or less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@joeshmo's answer is probably your best solution, but it might be worth giving this a try as well. It might be faster if you have a ton of users, but very few that have the skill you're looking for:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT user_id FROM skills WHERE skill_title = '$skills[0]')
    AND id IN (SELECT user_id FROM skills WHERE skill_title = '$skills[1]')
    ...
```

And your PHP script might look like this:

```
$skills = array("php", "css", ... ); // replace ... with the skills you are looking for
$whereClause = array();
for ($i=0, $count=count($skills); $i < $count; $i++)
    $whereClause[] = "id IN (SELECT user_id FROM skills WHERE skill_title = '{$skills[$i]}')";

$query = "SELECT * FROM users". (count($whereClause) > 0 ? " WHERE ". implode(" AND ", $whereClause) : "");
```

---

Another possible solution would be to use multiple `INNER JOIN`s, as @joeshmo suggested. You might be able to make it a bit smaller and cleaner by doing this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN skills s1 ON u.id = s1.user_id AND s1.skill_title = '$skills[0]'
    INNER JOIN skills s2 ON u.id = s2.user_id AND s2.skill_title = '$skills[1]'
    ...
```

So your PHP script might look something like this:

```
$skills = array("php", "css", ... );
$joins = array();
for ($i=0, $count=count($skills); $i < $count; $i++)
    $joins[] = "INNER JOIN skills s{$i} ON u.id = s{$i}.user_id AND s{$i}.skill_title = '{$skills[$i]}'";

$query = "SELECT * FROM users u ". implode(" ", $joins);
```

---

I would try both solutions to see which one performs better for your data set.

Comment: this works fine but i have to care with performance so is there any normalization to solve this issue

Comment: @SamyMassoud: See updated answer. I would also suggest making sure you have proper indexes on your tables. At least, you will probably want a `PRIMARY KEY (id)` on the `users` table and a `FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)` on your `skills` table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join it again for each skill you're searching for.

```
SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN skills as first_skill ON users.id = first_skill.user_id
INNER JOIN skills as second_skill ON users.id = second_skill.user_id
WHERE ($skill_title[0] LIKE first_skill.skill_title AND 
       $skill_title[1] LIKE second_skill.skill_title)
```

The problem with your query is that it is only joining the skills table once.  Your query works like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
id  | name | blah           | skill_title | level
-----------------------------------------------------
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | php         | good
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | css         | excellent
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | photoshop   | fair
2   | jhon | some thing     | php         | good
-----------------------------------------------------
```

No row has both css and php.  My query works like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id  | name | blah           | first_skill.skill_title | first_skill.level | second_skill.skill_title | second_skill.level |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | php                     | good              | php                      | good               |
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | php                     | good              | css                      | excellent          |
1   | Samy | stackoverflow  | php                     | good              | photoshop                | fair               |
... (there would be nine for Samy)
2   | jhon | some thing     | php                     | good              | php                      
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The second row has both `php` and `css`.  That's the one that would match.

This would be tedious for up to ten skills.  You could do multiple queries instead.

Comment: $skill_title is not static plus what i need is to get user with all required skills say for example (i need who have css,php,mysql) skills

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "$skill_title is not static", but it looks to me like this query *will* only get users with *all* the required skills.

Comment: @joeshmo: Couldn't you put the conditions in your WHERE clause directly in the JOIN conditions? Like `INNER JOIN skills AS first_skill ON users.id = first_skill.user_id AND first_skill.skill_title = '$skill_title[0]'`

Answer (score 0):

```
$skills = Array("php","css", ..... );
$query = "  select u.id, u.name from users u left join skills s on u.id=s.user_id "
        ."  where s.skill_title in (\"".implode($skills,"\",\"")."\") "
        ."  group by s.user_id having count(s.id) = ".count($skills);
```

Comment: I don't think you're using the [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function correctly. If you use it with one parameter, it should be just the array and there will be no *glue*. If you use it with two parameters, the first parameter is the *glue* (should be something like `"\", \""` for your example) and the second parameter should be the array. There is no three-parameter option.

Comment: sorry? i call it with two parameters actually, and implode accepts the parameters in any order

Comment: Interesting, so this is basically the or version above, but you make sure they have `n` matches.  This would fail though if they had php in there twice, right?

Comment: @guido: My mistake. I must have looked at it wrong, and thought the comma was a third parameter. Didn't know that you could switch the order of the two parameters.

Comment: @joeshmo yep, but he should normalize the schema using a join table with a two column primary key, and the problem goes away; using grouping is not actually like the or above, there only one join involved; but there is use of "in" which is fairly slow

Comment: @Travesty3 no worries, i just didn't understand your point and had actually not tested whether it was working before your comment